# regex how to only match two separate parts of one string

Tags: regex, string

Let's say we have a string:

```
John Smith has a birthday of 2/29/90
```

I'm using python `re.search`, which should just be normal regex. I DO NOT want the middle part. I only want the name and the date returned. Why does mine not work?

```
(?=(\(\w+\)))(?=([A-z]{3} (\d{1,2}) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))(\1)(\2)
```

EDIT:
see verified answer and comment

Comment: Can you show your code as a [mcve]? Are you using a raw string literal for the regex? Also, what defines a ["name"](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) here exactly? The regex shown seems to have no relation to the date string shown (lookaheads, colon delimiters, backreferences...). Thanks.

Comment: The OP has presented a test string, a desired result, a pattern and a question why it does not work. Voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string does not contain `(` or `)` so this `\(\w+\)` will not match.

The divider for the date part is `/` and not `:`

For a match, you don't need the positive lookaheads with backreferences to match it.

You can use 2 capturing groups instead.

Assuming the part of the name starts with uppercase chars as in the example:

```
([A-Z]\w+(?: [A-Z]\w*)*).*?(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY6Btz/1)

Or if the first 2 words are always the name

```
(\w+ \w{3,}).*?(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HXY3n9/1)

Note that `[A-z]` is [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) as `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: thank you for your help. I figured out the problem was my python as well. I did not want to return the 0th capture group, so I had to specify that with match_object.group(1,2)

Comment: @AnthonySpano You are welcome. I have voted to reopen the question.